# How do I install High Sierra on APFS external hard drives?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, external-disk, apfs, bootable-disk

How do I install High Sierra on APFS external hard drives?

I only want to boot High Sierra off the drive on RARE occasions, for testing purposes.  I don't care how slow it is, bad performance, etc..  The majority of the time, the drive would be home to an automated backup copy (SuperDuper).

I've been trying to install High Sierra for days now, and the installation always fails to continue after restart.  I can't figure it out.  I selected the wrong drive on one attempt and now I have a fully functional bootable APFS High Sierra thumb drive, but the external hard drive install still eludes me.

If this can't be done on external APFS HDDs, I would honestly expect the High Sierra installer to stop me when I try, give an error message to explain, and suggest a better option.

I'm happy to edit with any requested info.  I'm just not sure what's relevant.

Comment: I didn't think High Sierra would install to an APFS drive, only to HFS+, which it would then convert itself as part of the installation process.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I SWEAR I did it to an APFS external HDD just a few weeks ago, but I needed to re-format, so I gave it up.  Presently, I have installed successfully to APFS internal SSD, and to APFS thumb drive (I did another one on purpose, out of curiosity).

Comment: You could perhaps clone the working thumb drive to the HD? Up to Mojave, that's a valid method - it got tougher since. [I've never used Super Duper, but Carbon Copy Cloner can definitely do it.]

Comment: @Tetsujin, that's a very good idea.  I had it too and tried 4 times, but it would never boot.  I tried thumb drive SuperDupered into HDD, and thumb drive manually copied into HDD (yes, the invisible files too). SuperDuper copy showed up right away in Startup Disk, but no boot. Manual copy didn't boot either.  First Aid on both, retry, still no boots.  I also tried superduper and manual copy from an APFS SSD installed High Sierra that was fresh (never booted or set up) to HDD, and neither of those would boot either.  Also First Aided, still no luck

Comment: idk whether CCC has a free trial, but it *might* be worth a look… [My daily Mac is still on Mojave & it is superb on there… though I have never even seen SD in action for real comparison.]

Comment: @Tetsujin  I used to use CCC.  I can't remember why I switched to SuperDuper.  I don't have issues with either. Regarding my failing installs, the cloning was just a final attempt after I ran out of ideas to try.  I don't think SuperDuper is the issue, as I've tried countless methods of installing, plus I've varied the destination a few ways, to see if that was the cause.  I did TONS of testing, but no answer yet.

Comment: @Tesujin I gave CCC a shot with no success.  I tried a fresh High Sierra install pre-setup, and post-setup.  Both stop booting up and dump me into other drives that already work.  Still looking for a solution if anybody else has ideas...

Comment: I'm stumped:\ What Mac is it? I've used CCC to dupe existing boot drives for over a decade. It was great up to Mojave, never any issue at all. My standard method of 'migrating' to a new Mac was to just CCC the old drive to the new one. Every Mac in the house is a direct descendant of my first ever OS X Mac in the early 2ks. Even now I have an unmounted CCC of my boot drive in this Mac [still on Mojave], in case of failure.

Comment: @Tetsujin mid-2010 Macbook Pro 17". I have no doubt CCC works for you, but you havn't tried to boot High Sierra on an external APFS HDD that was cloned  from an APFS thumb drive OR an APFS SSD.

Comment: I've avoided the Sierras almost entirely [because they beak the laws of physics by being able to suck & blow at the same time;) so you're right, I have little experience with them, but depending on what it is you're actually trying to do, then El Capitan & Mojave are most stable - & I have thrown them about from Mac to Mac many times with no issues.

Comment: @Tetsijin, short simple answer, my laptop is too old to run Mojave or newer.  Longer answer, I'm saving up for a current one, even though there are plenty of options in between at lower prices.  Longest answer, condensed, I may have the exact same question, but about Mojave on APFS external hard drives.